# Axios POST Request using JWT in Vue3 and Django

Tags: axios, jwt, vuejs3, backend, web-frontend

Alright so as the title says I have a working Django application where my API creates a JWT key and saves it to my cookies. Now my frontend which is in Vue is supposed to send a form to the backend which is supposed to generate the jwt key and set it to my cookies. How do I go about this. My apologies if the writing is a little crude, I have been troubleshooting this for well over 4 hours. It shows me a 403 Forbidden error on my console.

Here's a snippet of my code for the frontend:

```
try {
    const response = await axios.post('link/', UserData)
    const jwtToken = response.data.jwt
    Cookies.set('jwt', jwtToken)
    this.confirmed = true
    console.log(this.confirmed)
}
catch(error) {
    console.log(error)
}
```

Everything is imported as it should be. But this is the underlying code. the django app sends a response with the jwt code. while this is not secure, it is needed for the troubleshoot. Please what can i do

I have fixed the issue, turns out i didnt add v-model in my vue form tag

Comment: so the backend couldnt verify the the JWT you sent from the frontend. what are you using for JWT in django? Do you have our custom authentication class or you are using something like DRF or django-jwt?

Comment: Using drf, jwt package I'd pyjwt